# Problem to Altium

Tags: altium

I installed a version of Altium (16). But in this software, PCB screen is invisible. Please look at the picture: [image]

As cab be seen, the black screen of PCB desktop is invisible. Schematic screen is normal. and I can design every circuit. but PCB screen not active. Also I changed this version of Altium to an old version but the problem still there!! Please help me to solve this ridiculous problem!!! Thanks guys.

Comment: Are you, by chance, running on a virtual machine?

Comment: And/or is this one of those hacked versions (and how did the hack work)? No idea if that could be the cause, but it may be important information. None of the legal ones on any of the PCs I worked with in various ways had problems with views.

Comment: Are you in 3D view mode? Press "2" on your keyboard and see if it changes.

Comment: As I can see you are not signed in. Which was the problem in this [case](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/229695/altium-pcbdoc-document-corrupt-generation#comment497326_229695).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your video card drivers then call Altium support.